# How can I make an "isAdmin" verification middleware?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, authentication, middleware

I have an authentication middleware, where I check through my route if the user is authenticated in the header with the security token

middlewareAuth

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

interface TokenPayload {
  id: string;
  iat: number;
  exp: number;
}

export default async function authMiddleware(
  req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction
  ) {
    const { authorization }  = req.headers;

    if (!authorization) {
      return res.status(401).json('Invalid Authorization');
    };

    const token = authorization.replace('Bearer', ' ').trim();

    try {
      const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET as string;
      const data = jwt.verify(token, secret);

      const { id } = data as TokenPayload;

      req.userId = id;

      return next();
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(401).json(err);
    }
}
```

I import this middleware in my route, thus verifying as I describe below:

```
import { Router } from "express";

import CreatePost from "../controllers/postControllers/CreatePost";

import authMiddleware from "../middlewares/AuthMiddlewares";

const router = Router();

router.post('/', authMiddleware, CreatePost.store);

export default router;
```

Within my user entity, I have a boolean called "isAdmin" which by default returns false. I would like a middleware that checks if also within my profile isAdmin is true and thus authenticate and put in the route along with AuthMiddleware. For that I tried to import my AuthMiddleware and verify, but without success.

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import authMiddleware from './AuthMiddlewares';

export default async function authAdminMiddleware(
    req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction,
) {
    authMiddleware(req, res, () => {
        if (req.userId.isAdmin) {
            next();
        } else {
            res.status(403).json("You are not alowed to do that!");
        }
    })
}
```

```
Property 'isAdmin' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)
```

What would be the most effective way to create this middleware? Can anyone give me some help? Thanks

Comment: You store only the `req.userId`, but you need to store the entire `req.user = data`.

Comment: Where exactly does this date come from?

Comment: I was referring to the statements `const { id } = data as TokenPayload; req.userId = id;` in your code.

Comment: Yes, but how could I import this into this new middleware? I mean, each middleware is in a different folder

Comment: You only need to change your `authMiddleware` function, for example, by adding the statement `req.user = data`.

Comment: You can chain middlewares, it's uncommon to use one middleware inside another

Comment: Could you post how I could do this Konrad?